# Why does it only returns only the first element of the array while i've already printed all the values of the array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

hy,

I want to get the value in an html tag, but it only returns the first value, and i don't know why... (I want the value of the html tag with the class "iHidden")

(I perfectly manage to get the values of the first input with the name="service[]" in my javascript)

```
while($service = $req->fetch()){ ?>

            <div class="form-control">
              <input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value="<?= $service['price']; ?>" id="<?= $i++ ?>">
              <p>id_service : <i class="iHidden"><?= $service['id_service']; ?></i></p>


              <label for="<?= $service['service'] ?>"><?= $service['service']; ?></label>
              <strong><?= $service['price']; ?>€</strong>
            </div>

    <?php } ?>
```

here's my javascript :

```
for(var i = 0; i <= totalService; i++){

    if($('#'+i).is(":checked")){

        // For the first input (it works)

        var total = $('#'+i).val();

        globalTotal = parseInt(globalTotal )+ parseInt(total); 

        // End for the first input



        // Here is the problem : it returns only the first value in my database...
        getI[i] = $('.iHidden').html();

        console.log(getI); // shows the first value


    }
}
```

When it click on "Calculer prix des services", I want it to show me the id of the service I checked. and if i checked the 2, I want it to show me the 2.

Thanks in advance for helping!

Comment: That's how `html()` function works

Comment: Here is an image to have a better idea : https://ibb.co/GTBwNKm

Comment: _"Get the HTML contents of the **first element** in the set of matched elements or set the HTML contents of every matched element._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method returns HTML content of the first element among the collection. In your case, `.iHidden` selects all elements with class `iHidden`.

[From docs:](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

> Get the HTML contents of the ***first element*** in the set of matched elements or set the HTML contents of every matched element.

For resolving the issue select based on the parent of the total element.Where [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method can be used for getting common ancestor and get the `iHidden` element using [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method.

```
getI[i] = $('#'+i).closest('.form-control').find('.iHidden').html();
```

---

**FYI :** *[From MDN docs:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)*

> Note: Using characters except ASCII letters, digits, '_', '-' and '.' may cause compatibility problems, as they weren't allowed in HTML 4. Though this restriction has been lifted in HTML 5, an ID should start with a letter for compatibility.

So it's better to start id value with a letter instead of a digit.

*For example :*

PHP

```
<input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value="<?= $service['price']; ?>" id="total<?= $i++ ?>">
```

JS

```
for (var i = 0; i <= totalService; i++) {
  var $tot = $('#total' + i);
  if ($tot.is(":checked")) {
    var total = $tot.val();
    globalTotal = parseInt(globalTotal) + parseInt(total);
    getI[i] = $tot.closest('.form-control').find('.iHidden').html();
    console.log(getI);
  }
}
```

Comment: @pandaD : glad to hear that :)